# Google App Script Web App Interaction

Tags: google-apps-script

I am creating a web app to communicate with a spreadsheet. The problem is, from the HTML file, I am calling on functions from the `.gs` file with my `doGet()` and a function called `doSomething()`. When I call on `doSomething` twice, it only executes once.

My HTML file (called `lolcatz.html`)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">
  </head>
  <body>
    <script>
      google.script.run.doSomething();
      google.script.run.doSomething2();
      google.script.run.doSomething();
      console.log("Hi");
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

My Google App script file (called `Code.gs`):

```
function doGet() {
  var page = HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('lolcatz.html');
  page.setTitle("Panther Time");
  return page;
}

function doSomething() {
  Logger.log('I was called!');
}
function doSomething2() {
  Logger.log('I was called! Again!');
}

function doStuff() {
  doSomething();
  doSomething2();
}
```

The log output:

```
[18-03-28 14:55:00:032 PDT] I was called!
```

The `console.log` command executes fine when I go to Inspect Element's JavaScript console.

I am well inside the execution limit and have the Google App Script API and the Google Sheets API enabled.

Answer (score 2):

## Short answer

The logs on Google Apps Script web IDE are cleared every time that a server-side function is called from the client side because google.script.run makes an asynchronous call and since they are asynchronous we can't sure what we will see on the Logs. If you want to keep the logs then use `console.log` instead con `Logger.log`.

## Test

To test how client-side code interacts with server-side code that use Logger, try this instead:

### lolcatz.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">
  </head>
  <body>
    <script>
      google.script.run.doSomething('I was called!');
      google.script.run.doSomething2('I was called to!');
      google.script.run.doSomething('I was called again!');
      console.log("Hi");
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

### Code.gs

```
function doGet() {
  var page = HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('lolcatz.html');
  page.setTitle("Panther Time");
  return page;
}

function doSomething(message) {
  Logger.log(message);
}
function doSomething2(message) {
  Logger.log(message);
}
```

## After opening the Web App

### Execution transcript

From View > Execution transcript

> [18-03-28 17:36:00:403 CST] Starting execution
>   [18-03-28 17:36:00:412 CST] Logger.log([I was called again!, []]) [0 seconds]
>   [18-03-28 17:36:00:414 CST] Execution succeeded [0.002 seconds total runtime]

### Logs

From View > Logs

> [18-03-28 17:36:00:412 CST] I was called again!

### Changing Logger.log by console.log

After changing Logger.log by console.log an opening the web app again (or refreshing the tab)

From View > Stackdriver Logging

> 2018-03-28 17:43:50.859 CST  I was called!
>   2018-03-28 17:43:51.073 CST  I was called to!
>   2018-03-28 17:43:51.233 CST  I was called again!

Comment: Afraid Not... nothing showing up on the Google Cloud system, and the in-app logs are returning `[18-03-28 21:39:59:286 EDT] I was called again!`. I have been doing some snooping and have found some [outage](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/support/outage-log) has been going on.

Comment: @Stiffy2000 Are you using the URL ending on `/dev` to do your tests?

Comment: Yes, the URL ends with `/dev`